# Comparing string and unicode in Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I wonder why when I make:

```
a = [u'k',u'ę',u'ą']
```

and then type:

```
'k' in a
```

I get `True`, while:

```
'ę' in a
```

will give me `False`?

It really gives me headache and it seems someone made this on purpose to make people mad...

Comment: For what it's worth, this behaves as you expect in Python 3.

Comment: On my Python (2.7.2), this raises the warning `UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal` before returning `False`, which is the reason for it. Using `u'ę' in a` works as expected.

Comment: @alKid, I just pasted it in my interpreter.

Comment: Does the interpreter handle unicode input?

Comment: I'm using python `2.7.15`, `'ę' in a` is True, which is strange...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**And why is this?**

In Python 2.x, you can't compare unicode to string directly for non-ascii characters. This will raise a warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

However, in Python 3.x this doesn't appear, as all strings are unicode objects.

**Solution?**

You can either make the string unicode:

```
>>> u'ç' in a
True
```

Now, you're comparing both unicode objects, not unicode to string.

Or convert both to an encoding, for example utf-8 before comparing:

```
>>> c = u"ç"
>>> u'ç'.encode('utf-8') == c.encode('utf-8')
True
```

Also, to use non-ascii characters in your program, you'll have to specify the encoding, at the top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#the whole program
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly make the string unicode. The following shows an example, and the warning given when you do not specify it as unicode:

```
>>> a = [u'k',u'ę',u'ą']
>>> 'k' in a
True
>>> 'ę' in a
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
>>> u'ę' in a
True
```

Comment: @KulawyKrul See my answer for that

Answer (score 1):

`u'ę'` is a `unicode` object, while `'ę'` is a `str` object in your current locale.  Sometimes, depending on locale, they will be the same, and sometimes they will not.

One of the nice things about Python 3 is that all text is unicode, so this particular problem goes away.

Comment: Seems I need to start using Python 3 immediately! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you [specify the source code encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and use `u` in front of unicode literals.

This works both on Python 3 and Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = [u'k',u'ę',u'ą']

print(u'ę' in a)
# True
```